# Can I prioritize sort columns in SQL based on an external table

Tags: sql-server, sorting, dynamic-sql

I am working with a table that has several columns that potentially could be sorted based on a user setting.  I am trying to come up with a way that avoids dynamic SQL and storing a sort string in a preference table.

An example of the data I am working with:

```
User   |  VIP  |  Date    | Priority  |  Location
---------------------------------------------------
 Jim   |   1   | 1/1/2019 |    0      |    105
 Joe   |   0   | 2/1/2019 |    0      |    104
 Jack  |   1   | 1/5/2019 |    1      |    105
 John  |   0   | 2/6/2019 |    1      |    106
 Jane  |   0   | 4/1/2019 |    1      |    105
 Jake  |   1   | 7/1/2019 |    0      |    105
```

The sort table would look something like this

```
Column   |  SortOrder |  Location
------------------------------------
 VIP     |      2     |    105
 Date    |      1     |    105
Priority |      -1    |    105
 VIP     |      1     |    104
 Date    |      2     |    104
Priority |      3     |    104
 VIP     |      1     |    106
 Date    |      -1    |    106
Priority |      2     |    106
```

My query would be using location as a where clause, so i would only be returning values for a specific location, but I would like to sort the data for that location based on the values set in the sort table.

-1 would be an inactive sort, so if the location was 105, I would want to order by Date then VIP.  If 104, VIP, then Date, Then Priority and if 106 VIP then Priority without Date being considered.

I was thinking I could maybe do some kind of math thing, but I am having a hard time coming up with an algorithm.

I am trying to avoid hard coding  Date ASC, VIP ASC into a table and retrieving it and applying it via Dynamic SQL (though I do have that working, but I am hoping for a better, Non Dynamic, solution).

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is it me, or am I correctly understanding that your ordering differs per row, depending on the value of `LocationID`? Also, what does the `Sort Order` `-1` represent?

Comment: is your query send by a client application ? Then let that client build the `order by` based on this table

Comment: @Larnu that's correct.  The sort order would be set by each location.  Sort Order -1 is that is inactive, so it's not considered in the sort.

Comment: @GuidoG I cannot set it on the client side.  This query is inside a stored procedure that will get product orders from our database and based on the warehouse (location) order the importance of the field to that location.

Comment: I don't see a way to do this server-side without using dynamic SQL.  That said, @GuidoG is correct that, since this requirement is client-location-specific, the ordering should be handled by the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with math.

You can either use dynamic SQL, as you mentioned, or use a bunch of CASES.

First you would need to either PIVOT or use Subqueries or some other method to get virtual SortOrder columns for each of the columns you might ORDER BY.   Then you could do something like this:

```
ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN [VipSortOrder]=1 THEN [VIP]
  WHEN [DateSortOrder]=1 THEN [Date]
  WHEN [PrioritySortOrder]=1 THEN [Priority]
END,
  CASE {Same for the 2's} etc...
```

If it were me, I'd use dynamic sql, personally.

Comment: I ended up doing a form of dynamic sql, but not from the client.  I wrote a function that tool the location ID in and got the list of columns in order where the sortorder was greater than 0.  I put it in a cursor and looped over it to create a string and returned it from the function.  Then using dynamic SQL, I injected the order by clause into my code.